# How to use Ninject2 with WCF?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject-2

In a short view of the IoC and DI .NET libraries I chose to use Ninject2.
According to DDD style in:

- Infrastructure: I have Entity Framework 4.0 .edmx model and the Repository implementation
- Domain Layer: I have POCO objects and Repository Interfaces (implemented in Infrastructure)
- Application Services: I have WCF services that call methods defined in repository interfaces from Domain Layer.

My question is how to inject a Repository in WCF with Ninject2. I have read some articles with Ninject2 but are presented very simple example ( ex.: dependency injection in the same class library).
Any indication would be useful:).

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you download the Ninject 2 [WCF extensions](http://ninject.org/extensions) you should be able to do this quite nicely.

The main differences are that your svc file has a Factory entry:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService.YourService" CodeBehind="YourService.svc.cs" Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

and your global.asax.cs file inherits from NinjectWcfApplication:

```
namespace WcfService
{
    public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
```

The rest of the code and service examples can be found [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/tree/master/src/Examples).

Comment: Thanks, dude. That's the answer even if it hasn't been accepted as such.